# Migration from tomcat to wildfly

Tags: wildfly-10, context-param

I am migrating my web application from tomcat to wildfly. I was able to deploy the app using a temporary workaround of placing the configurations inside the WEB-INF/web.xml (). But I wanted it outside my war file. Is there any equivalent for catalina/conf/localhost/myapplicationconfig.xml in wildfly. Any suggestions please. I tried naming subsytem configuration and also placing it in modules but it didn't work for me

Comment: What were the errors? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to place the contents of web.xml to another file myapplication.xml and trying to refer the context in the code. but the code gives null value

Comment: I don't think that is possible. The `web.xml` would be parsed at deployment time and information needs to be known then. I don't think you can use an external file like that.

Comment: there is an option in tomcat to accomplish it. So wanted to know whether there is an equivalent in wildfly.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? It's an important feature for multi-tenant deployments.